# how to find cell index no. in 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-address

in C programming  if an 2-D array is given like ( int a[5][3]) and base address and address of particular element (cell ) is also given and have to find index no. of that element(cell)  (row and col no.)  can we find that? if yes how?

i know the formula of finding address is like this

int a[R][C];

address(a[i][j])=ba+size(C*i+ j);

if ba, R,C,Size and address(a[i][j]) is given... how to find value of i and j?

for finding the value of 2 variable we need 2 equation ..but im not able to find 2nd equation.

Comment: `i = (address-ba)/C; j = (address-ba)%C;`

Answer (score 1):

Use integer division and remainder operators.

If you have the `base` and a pointer to an element, `elt`, then there are two things:

1. In "pure math" terms, you'll have to divide by the size of the elements in the array.
2. In "C" terms, when you subtract pointers this division is performed for you.

For example:

```
int a[2];

ptrdiff_t a0 = (ptrdiff_t)&a[0];
ptrdiff_t a1 = (ptrdiff_t)&a[1];

a1 - a0; // likely 4 or 8.
```

This will likely be 4 or 8 because that's the likely size of `int` on whatever machine you're using, and because we performed a "pure math" subtraction of two numbers.

But if you let C get involved, it tries to do the math for you:

```
int a[2];

int * a0 = &a[0];
int * a1 = &a[1];

a1 - a0; // 1
```

Because C knows the type, and because it's **the law,** the subtracted numbers get divided by the size of the type automatically, converting the pointer difference into an array-like index or offset.

This is important because it will affect how you do the math.

Now, if you know that the address of `elt` is `base + SIZE * (R * i + j)` you can find the answer with integer division (which may be performed automatically for you), subtraction, more integer division, and either modulus or multiply&subtract:

1. offset or number = elt - base. This will either give you an index (C style) or a numeric (pure math) difference, depending on how you do the computation.
2. offset = number / SIZE.  This will finish the job, if you need it.
3. i = offset / R. Integer division here - just throw away the remainder.
4. j = offset - (i*R) OR j = offset % R. Pick what operation you want to use: multiply & subtract, or modulus.

Comment: Why do you cast to `unsigned long` instead of `ptrdiff_t`? In theory this might truncate the address.

Comment: My bad. I started with ul, then switched to pdt and forgot to update. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

- The specific address minus the base address gives you the size in bytes, from the base to the specific address.
- If you divide that size in bytes with `sizeof(ba[0][0])` (or `sizeof(int)`), you get the number of items.
- `items / C` gives you the first dimension and `items % C` gives you the second dimension.

Thus:

```
int ba[R][C];
uintptr_t address = (uintptr_t)&ba[3][2]; // some random item

size_t items = (address - (uintptr_t)ba) / sizeof(ba[0][0]);
size_t i = items / C;
size_t j = items % C;
```

It is important to carry out the arithmetic with some type that has well-defined behavior, therefore `uintptr_t`.

If I had done `int* address` then `address - ba` would be nonsense, since `ba` decays into an array pointer of type  `int(*)[3]`. They aren't compatible types.